# why failure login attempt redirects to other page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, authentication, myspace

Why is failure login redirects to other login page and not on the same page. I noticed this in most social networks like facebook, myspace and etc. I their a signicance?

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a user friendly feature, to enable/assist a user to take proper action so that he can  retrieve his login details. Just imagine if a user just types wrong password a few times and goes off else where. For any successful web site, any action by user which results in failure (due to any reasons) must be assisted with help links or possible solutions or a friendly message. This is to satisfy and retain the user for longest possible time on the site.